# What to do after make test fails?

Tags: building, apr, openbsd

On VirtualBox VM OpenBSD:

I was trying to build apr 1.5.1 in my attempt to build an apache 2.4 server WITHOUT packages( ie. from source ) and when I ran `make test`, testlock failed with:

```
testlock   : -Line 300: Timer returned too late FAILED 1 of 4

...

*** Error 1 in test (Makefile:186 'check')
*** Error 1 in /a/b/c/d/e/f (Makefile:127 'check')
```

I have no idea what to do with it.  What is the course of action for something like this?

Comment: This might be a [known issue](http://mononoco.com/pukiwiki/index.php?CentOS%205.3%2FAPR)... are you using CentOS?

Comment: @summea Looks like that's it, but is there an English version of that page?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there's an English version... Was the _apr_ source code from one of the OpenBSD packages sites? _(Also, which version are you installing?)_ Maybe somebody can help you more than I can with that sort of additional information...

Comment: apr 1.5.1, the newest that apache has.

Comment: Have you tried using a slightly older version of _apr_, perhaps one from an OpenBSD package site ([somewhere like this*](http://www.openbsd.org/4.6_packages/i386.html))? _*Note: any downloads and installations that you choose to make from sites like these are your decision. Make sure to read related documentation for compatibility information, too, before making a decision about installing software on your VM!_ Also, your version of OpenBSD may make a difference for what package site would be best to use... the OpenBSD packages site above is just an example of what these sites may look like.

Comment: Post your comment as an answer, it deserves the check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try using a slightly older version of ***apr***; perhaps one from an OpenBSD packages site (somewhere like [this OpenBSD Packages site](http://www.openbsd.org/4.6_packages/i386.html)?)

***Note:*** any downloads and installations that you choose to make from sites like these are your decision. Please make sure to read related documentation for compatibility information, too, before making a decision about installing software in your environment!

Also, your version of OpenBSD may make a difference for what package site would be best to use... the OpenBSD packages site above is just an example of what these sites may look like.

For future reference, you can find more information about these sort of packages in the [OpenBSD packages and ports documentation](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html).